# Implementing non-blocking Retry Mechanism in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

@Retryable annotation in Spring Retry mechanism is blocking thread during retry. Do we have any retry mechanism which is not blocking thread for a particular task during backoff time and can execute other tasks  ?

With @Retryable annotation, the thread that performs the whole retry policy and remains blocked during backoff time.

Answer (score 0):

Spring now has  non blocking retry

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/RetryableTopic.html

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry-kafka-consumer

https://betterprogramming.pub/spring-boot-kafka-non-blocking-retries-a-hands-on-tutorial-a0c425acc3dd

Comment: That is only when using Apache Kafka; spring-retry itself does not support non-blocking retry.